# file size is changed when do export to excel option in document library

Tags: 2013, 2010, document-library

I have a document center site collection and an document library which has some documents when i export to excel option from library when the excel book downloaded from sharepoint the file size changed for example

file size showing in doclibrary in KB 448 KB but in excel it showing 458126
here how its file size is changed ?

Comment: is the new size in KB or B or MB?

Comment: this is i want to check , how it was changed

Comment: 448 KB is 458752 bytes ( 458752 / 1024 = 448). I suppose there is a small distinction due to how Windows is calculating the remaining and used space on the disk, that's why the difference is (458126 vs 458752). Could you check and write back the size of the downloaded file?